# Only menus shown on MODX Manager

Tags: ckeditor, modx, modx-revolution

After I changed a setting in the ckeditor plugin, the content of the whole manager doesn't load. Only the menus (top and left) are shown. I've already cleared the cache by deleting the content of the `core/cache` folder, and the cache from my browser.

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Comment: Cant get there, the whole content field is gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `core/components/ckeditor` folder and clear cache again. Login in the manager, go to packages Manager and remove the ckeditor and reinstall. This is also a way to remove manually packages in modx.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case, also check if you have enabled the compress_js and compress_css options in the system setting (check them with a database administration tool like phpmyadmin) and set them to false if so.

You can verify that this is your problem by opening the development tools of your browser (f12 for chrome and internet explorer and richght click and push q on the keyboard) and look for any loading errors of js or css files.

Hope that helps :)77